# Login failed: Firebase: Error (auth/user-not-found)

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication

When I Login with the correct credientials the alert thats being pulled is Login failed: Firebase: Error (auth/user-not-found). . Below is my javascript code. I've tried making new users and more.

Javascript:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from         "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { setLogLevel } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-app.js"; //         Import setLogLevel from firebase/app

 const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL",
    projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
    appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
    measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID"
  };

 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const auth = getAuth();

 // Set Firebase debugging to get detailed error messages
 setLogLevel("debug");

 const loginForm = document.querySelector("#loginForm");
 const loginEmail = document.querySelector("#loginEmail");
 const loginPassword = document.querySelector("#loginPassword");

 loginForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const userEmail = loginEmail.value;
const userPassword = loginPassword.value;

try {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmail, userPassword);
    const user = userCredential.user;
    window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
   } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    alert("Login failed: " + errorMessage);
   }
    });
```

Comment: did you already create the User? the current code is for _signing in_ once the account was _already_ created. the best way to check is to create a new user manually from within the firebase console and then try to sign in.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work still